# Timetable / schedule planner

Tags: time-management

I am looking for a software (preferrably mac or web) to create (weekly repeating) schedules with the following features:

- creation and management of different rooms / resources with distinct start and end times
- creation of different time blocks with labels / different usages
- statistics of how many hours in rooms are allocated to which block / group

No multi-user an no booking component needed, just a visual weekly planning and reporting of the allocated time slots.
At the moment this is done with Excel but I am looking for a better solution.
Schedule repeates every week so just Mo-Su is needed as time dimension

[image]